# Relations setState and child component

Tags: reactjs

I made some app to get asynchronously data from remote server. 
The app just parent component - to get data, and two child components.

One child component for display asynchronous data.
Other child for filter functionality. Just input string where user typing and data in first component display appropriate items.

There are a lot code with **console.log** everywhere, but in simple scheme it:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {isLoading:true, query:''}

  getData = (location) => {
    axios.get(endPoint).then(response=>{ response.map((item) => { places.push(item)})
                                         // *****  first setState
                                         this.setState({isLoading:false})
                                       })
    }

  updateQuery = (e) => {
    // *****  second setState
    this.setState({query:e.target.value.trim()})
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getData(location)
  }
  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoading){
      if (this.state.query){
        const match = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(this.state.query),'i')
        searchTitles = places.filter(function(item){return match.test(item.name)})
      }else{
        searchTitles = places.slice();
      }
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
          <input type='text' onChange={this.updateQuery} value={this.state.query}/>
          <List places = {searchTitles}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When state change in case of using  everything is OK - content refreshed in next child component.

But child component that display data - some items not full of content... no photos and some text information. So probably its rendered before getting remote data.

But why its not re-render it after **state.isLoad** toggled to **'false'** (in code - after got response) ?

I put among code **console.log** to track processes ... and weird things: **state.isLoad** switched to **false** before some part of data came from server. (((

I dont use **ShouldComponentUpdate()** inside child component.

Comment: Changing props or state triggers a rerender of the component (unless its specifically setup to avoid this), which of course includes all other components that are rendered as part of the component.

Comment: I edited my Ques in more details. Would you look at it ?

Comment: You're using a lot of undefined variables like `location` and `places` – please make a [mcve].

Comment: I delete all this string that defined variables... - code above - just simplified scheme... its show general way of implementing.

Comment: I think you wrong in your opinion: **Changing props or state triggers a rerender of the component (unless its specifically setup to avoid this)**  According this [article:] (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781)  re-render started  in child component only if `render()` have props that got  `STATE` directly from parent.

Answer (score 0):

Per React's [documentation for `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> `setState()` will always lead to a re-render unless
>   `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns false.

As mentioned, one way to avoid a re-render is `shouldComponentUpdate` returning `false` (`shouldComponentUpdate` takes in `nextProps` and `nextState`) but it's not clear why someone would trigger a state change with `setState` and then nullify that state change with `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: I think you wrong in your opinion: **setState() will always lead to a re-render unless  shouldComponentUpdate() returns false.**  According this [article:] (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781)  re-render started  in child component only if `render()` have props that got  `STATE` directly from parent.